# d3 line chart flattens during update

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 line chart as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmcconechy/qca39/)

The chart looks and works great initially but i am having an issue updating. In the fiddle press the update button.

Why does the line just flatten and not show the data updated as I would expect?

I suspect the problem is around this line in the update function at the top.

```
         svg.select(".line")  
            .transition().duration(750)
            .attr("d",  valueline(chartData));
```

But i cant workout why the line exactly the line is flattened/incorrect?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the `domain` of the `y` scale correctly:

```js
y.domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function(d) { return d.close; })]) // original
```

instead of:

```js
y.domain([0, d3.max(chartData, function(d) { return d.value; })]) // fix
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qca39/1/)